# Getting error 500 while using Ajax call in ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to call a simple void in html page but it shows error 500.
Can anyone help me i'm getting crazy!
In console log shows this error :

```
POST http://localhost:15041/Default.aspx/SaveUser 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

my html code :

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True"></asp:ScriptManager>


    </form>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Default.aspx/SaveUser",
            data: "{id:'1'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("SUCCESS: " + msg.d);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("FAILURE");
            }
        });
</script>
</body>
```

and here is my C# code :

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod]
        public static int SaveUser(int param)
        {
            return 10;
        }
```

Comment: change your data to : data: "{param:'1'}",

Comment: Thank you very much i forgot to change param, another question: i was reading that microsoft is not supporting WebMethods anymore, is it true? What should i do?

Comment: Where did you read that? Am sure it is not true, If it is you can always create web api or wcf service and serve your web application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Zaki commented, that was my mistake, I should change data part of ajax to :
data:"{param:'1'}"